# How to do alter table using Check Constraint - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, alter-table, check-constraints

```
CREATE TABLE publishers
(
    PublisherName    varchar(75),
    City                    varchar(35),
    PublisherState    char(2),
    Country            varchar(4)
)
GO
```

-- modify publishers so that state must be two letters

```
ALTER TABLE publishers
    ALTER COLUMN publisherstate char(2) CHECK (publisherstate LIKE '[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]')​
```

Comment: Are you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mention the `Constraint Name` and `Check`.

Try this:

```
alter table publishers
add constraint codeCheck check (PublisherState like '[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]');
```